# What is the relationship between a solar panel's open-circuit voltage and panel irradiance?

Tags: solar-cell

Is there a relationship between a cell's insolation intensity and open-circuit voltage? In other words, assuming all other factors are equal, if I test a panel in full daylight on the earth, and then move it farther from the sun (e.g. Mars) how (mathematically) would I see the open-circuit voltage change?

Comment: Think about it this way: if you were to take the solar panel into deep space, to the point that the sun looks like just another star in the sky, would you expect to still see the same voltage?

Comment: @Hearth Thanks for the feedback. Of course not, and I'm fixing the body. The title captures my question, the body is wrong in asking "the same".

Comment: @Hearth BTW, in case that wasn't clear, that was a sincere thanks. Without your comment I might have been left scratching my head why my question was being downvoted.

Comment: Have you considered the effect of the Earth's atmosphere? Found [Absorption Bands and Atmospheric Windows](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/features/RemoteSensing/remote_04.php) but haven't checked the absorption at the wavelengths used by solar panels.

Comment: @ChesterGillon not in the slightest! But my question was perfectly answered by V.V.T. I'm not sending anything to Mars, it was just a good "far enough away to be different, but not so far that the comparison was absurd". Most sites about solar cells discuss power and irradiance, and that's a very clear relationship, but O.C. and voltage is not (as seen by V.V.T.'s excellent worked example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solar cell's open-circuit voltage \$V_{OC}\$ is approx. \$V_{TH}·\ln(I_L/I_S+1)\$, where \$V_{TH}\$ is the thermal voltage, ca. 26mV @ 300K, \$I_S\$ is the diode saturation current, \$I_L\$ is the light-induced photocurrent. For high-quality silicon panels, \$V_{OC}\$ can exceed 0.7 volts in direct sunlight (Wikipedia).

Now, \$\ln\left((I_L/I_S)+1\right)\$ is approx. \$700mV/26mV \approx 27\$; \$I_L \approx \exp(27)·I_S\$ and \$I_L \gg I_S\$. Neglecting the power spectral difference, the light-induced photocurrent is proportional to sunlight irradiance. Martian direct sunlight irradiance is 43% of Earth's; \$I_{L.Martian} = 0.43·I_{L.Earth}\$. The ambient temperature is also lower, but still can reach 293K, so let \$V_{TH}\$ is the same 26mV.

So, for Mars, we write down (remember, \$I_L \gg I_S\$, and we neglect '+1' in logarithm arg):

$$
V_{OC} = V_{TH}·\ln\left((I_{L.Martian}/I_S)+1\right) \approx \\
V_{TH}·\ln\left(0.43·I_{L.Earth}/I_S\right) = \\ 
V_{TH}·\left(\ln(I_{L.Earth}/I_S) + \ln(0.43)\right)\ = \\
V_{TH}·\left(\ln(I_{L.Earth}/I_S)\right) + V_{TH}·\left(\ln(0.43)\right)\ = \\
0.7 - 0.026·\ln(0.43) = 0.67V
$$

At Mars, the solar cell's open-circuit voltage is 30mV lower, not that much of a decrease.

Comment: Great answer. One question: why is $I_s$ representing a *voltage*? Wouldn't it have made more sense as $V_s$? And how do those units work out? Is it maybe that $I_s$ is a diode saturation current?

Comment: Great typo: \$I_S\$ is a saturation **current**. Certainly, there is no diode parameter named 'saturation voltage' -- at least, for well-known diodes ;)

Comment: There was a minor typo in the worked math, and while running it to ground I found https://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/solar-cell-operation/effect-of-light-intensity. Neat calculator, gives exactly the expected results.